# Getting WordPress to work inside a rails 3 application

Tags: database, htaccess, wp-config, configuration, virtual-hosts

I am migrating an existing WordPress blog into a subdirectory of a new rails 3 app (deployed on Apache2 / Ubuntu 10).

I have PHP/MySQL installed, and I have a standard rails app folder structure in the production env:

```
/var/www/railsapp/public/
```

Inside `/public/`, I want to copy the Wordpress files into `/home/blog/`, so:

```
../public/home/blog/-wp stuff-
```

I've already migrated all the files as well as the database, and updated wp-config.php per the directons given in the Wordpress codex.

However, when I try to access the blog: (`www.example.com/home/blog`), I get a 403-forbidden message.

I've already ensured my vhost config is setup correctly (I can access the rails app without issue) and the http.d directive is as follows:

```
<Directory /var/www/railsapp/public/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

My `../home/blog/.htaccess` file is also correct (I believe):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Create a file in your blog folder. Call it test.html. Can you access it? If you can't then this isn't really a WordPress issue, and would probably be best dealt with at ServerFault or Webmasters

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but rather a suggestion: why not setup your blog on a subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but handled the VirtualHost configuration in a different way:

1. Used an Apache mod_alias to redirect what for you is `/home/blog/` to a path outside of `/var/www/railsapp/public/` (e.g., `/var/www/wordpress`)
2. Then, for that new hosted directory I had to declare `PassengerEnabled off` to avoid getting the standard rails error message.

I've wrote this up in more detail in a blog post about [hosting wordpress in a rails subdirectory](http://blog.dpdearing.com/2011/11/hosting-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-of-an-existing-rails-application/).  My `VirtualHost` declaration ended up looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/mydomain.com/public
    Options FollowSymLinks

    # an Alias for the wordpress blog
    Alias /blog /srv/www/mydomain.com/wordpress
    <Directory /srv/www/mydomain.com/wordpress>
        PassengerEnabled off
        AllowOverride all   # make the WordPress .htaccess file work
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```